# IncompatibleClassChangeError in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

After learning Lambda Expressions in Java, I tried to practice some simple examples. But in my first example only I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:384)
at com.example.lambda.HelloLambda.main(HelloLambda.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metaFactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodHandle,MethodType)CallSite/invokeStatic
at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:763)
at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:880)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1019)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1284)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:382)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metaFactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:852)
at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:877)
... 4 more
```

The error seems an error because of backward compatibility issue. But don't know how to fix this. Many answers in StackOverFlow suggested Recompilation could fix this issue. But still I am getting this error.

My code

```
package com.example.lambda;

public class HelloLambda {

static String firstname = "ChanSek";
static String lastname = "Nayak";

interface HelloService {
      String hello();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        HelloService helloService = 
            () -> {String hello="Hello " + firstname + " " + lastname; 
                           return hello;};
    System.out.println(helloService.hello());
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine. But running gives the above mentioned error.

I am using JDK1.8.0 snapshot.

[image: ScreenShot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: You need to download [JDK 8 with Lambda Support](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/). Check to see, if you have downloaded that JDK only.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes of course I have downloaded JDK1.8.0. Otherwise it would not compile at all.

Comment: This runs fine for me. Are you using the JVM that comes with the JDK? Also what build number are you using? Earlier versions were buggy

Comment: Runs fine for me too.

Comment: JDK 8 Downloaded from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html and Eclipse from http://downloads.efxclipse.org/eclipse-java8/2013-05-19/

Comment: @ChandraSekhar. That version JDK 8 does not have lambda support yet. You need to download from the link I posted in my comment. And I don't think Eclipse-Java 8 support Lambda expressions either - but I'm not sure of this. You can use ItelliJ Idea rather.

Comment: @RohitJain Can you please check the screenshots I have posted. If anything worng, then I will correct it. Otherwise I will download from the link given by you. Actually the two links I have downloaded from is recommended in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/lambda-1984522.html

Answer (score 1):

Is it possibly because of this?

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8019635

The way lambdas have been done in Java 8 has changed, very recently (07/2013), in a **not backwards compatible** way.

If you've somehow managed to compile with a compiler which talks PRE beta 103 lambdas, but are running with a JRE of POST 103 lambdas, you'll have problems.

(The hint for me here is that the metafactory name used to be mixed case, but in java 1.8.0 beta 103 appears to be lower case - you're searching for mixed case, but not finding it.)